# How to add dates to an array?

Tags: vb.net

I want to add dates to an array given start and end dates.

I already tried declaring it as an Array and an ArrayList but it gave the same error at the same exact line. Here is the sample code:

```
Dim startP As DateTime = New DateTime(2019, 3, 27)
Dim endP As DateTime = New DateTime(2019, 3, 30)
Dim CurrD As DateTime = startP
Dim DateArray As ArrayList

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    While (CurrD <= endP)
        DateArray.Add(CurrD)
        CurrD = CurrD.AddDays(1)
    End While
End Sub
```

Both gave the error "NullReferenceException was unhandled"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error due to not initialize `DateArray.` Do it like :

```
Dim DateArray As New ArrayList
```

Answer (score 2):

Lists are probably a better choice.  Note how the list in the example is initialized.

```
Dim startP As DateTime = New DateTime(2019, 3, 27)
Dim endP As DateTime = New DateTime(2019, 3, 30)
Dim CurrD As DateTime = startP
Dim DateArray As New List(Of DateTime)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    While (CurrD <= endP)
        DateArray.Add(CurrD)
        CurrD = CurrD.AddDays(1)
    End While
    'where you need an array of DateTime do
    '   DateArray.ToArray
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
  Dim date_array As New List(Of Date)
  date_array.Add(New Date()) ' add as much as you want in a loop or manually
  date_array.ToArray() ' to return an array of dates..
```